# Что значит бинарная совместимость в Java?

Tags: java, терминология

Что значит `бинарная совместимость` в Java?

Comment: старайтесь не вырывать фразу из контекста или хотя бы давать ссылку на то, где вы её взяли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Java это значит, что байт-код скомпилированный один раз не требует перекомпиляции при смене среды исполнения. Меняется только виртуальная машина Java, которая для каждой платформы своя. Таким образом достигается бинарная совместимость и кросс-платформенность Java.